# Copy into snowflake to get single file from s3

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have written a snowflake stored proc in snowflake, but stuck on COPY INTO snowflake sql. Our files on s3 are stored without extension in numerical format:

```
E.g:
12
1245
12456
12567
```

Now the problem is when I pass the exact file path to snowflake like `s3://bucket_name/folder/12` it copies all files in s3 starting with 12. I have the following piece of code:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TABLE sbfe_json (request_id INT, source_json VARIANT);

copy into sbfe_json
from (SELECT '12', t.* from '@external_stages/12' as t)
file_format = (type='json');
```

I have tried using pattern instead with `pattern='^12$'`, however, this doesn't load anything. It does not pick the file 12 at all.

Comment: would `'@external_stages/12$` work? you only want the end token to hard match

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim nope nothing gets processed.

Comment: this might be part of the reason the standard advise is to use hierarchical paths to allow load time A before looking at time B and needing to reduce S3 load (pulling to many file listings back from S3)

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
copy into sbfe_json
from (SELECT '12', t.* from '@external_stages/12' as t)
file_format = (type='json')
pattern='^12.*';
```

The pattern matches all files, which are starting with "12".

Comment: nothing gets loaded, the problem is snowflake is not picking up any pattern except .*12